# How to select a child element of several classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

If I have several divs which all have individual class names, is there a way to select a common child element between them?
In the example below I have three divs (out of 5) which have a common color set for the content in all their child classes.
If I want to select the h2 element in these three divs (and not my other two, which also have h2's) is there a way to specify this with a psuedo-selector without giving a common class to the h2 elements?

```
.item--purple, .item--grey, .item--black {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.item--purple h2, .item--grey h2, .item--black h2 {
    color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}
```

I tried putting h2 after each class, which works but is long-winded, I can't work out any other way to do it.

Comment: Generate your css with a preprocessor like Sass. Then you only have to type H2 once and it will be generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like:
Add class "general" (or whatever you like to name it) to the parent elements.
Then select it with:
.general > h2